# ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

```
homicide_scatter_df.plot.scatter(x='Homicide',y='Area Name',s = 225,
                                c = 'Population/mil', colormap='viridis', 
                                 sharex=False)
```

The code above works and I get my scatterchart with the dots changing colour depending on the area population.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

ax.scatter(x = homicide_scatter_df['Homicide'], 
           y = homicide_scatter_df['Area Name'],
           s = 225,
           c = 'Population/mil', colormap='viridis',
           sharex=False)
```

However, the code above throws an error regarding `c`:

> ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not Population/mil

---

**Update:** After fixing the column issue, there is still an issue with the colour bar.

On the right of the pandas chart I get a colour range bar with the label "Population/mil". The matplotlib version does not present the same colour bar with a range of colours. Is it possible to get the same colour bar using the second method?

**Update:** I now have the colour bar, but the colours are in the opposite order to the data.

```
norm = colors.Normalize(homicide_scatter_df['Population/mil'].max(), homicide_scatter_df['Population/mil'].min())
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm,cmap='YlGnBu'), ax=ax)
```

The above code shows the bar in the correct place and with the correct values. However, the colour is in the opposite order to the dots colour.

How can I change the colours to ascend the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pandas plot, `c='Population/mil'` works because pandas already knows this is a column of `homicide_scatter_df`.

In the matplotlib plot, you need to either pass the full column like you did for `x` and `y`:

```
ax.scatter(x=homicide_scatter_df['Homicide'], 
           y=homicide_scatter_df['Area Name'],
           c=homicide_scatter_df['Population/mil'], # actual column, not column name
           s=225, colormap='viridis', sharex=False)
```

Or if you specify the [`data`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) source, then you can just pass the column names similar to pandas:

> `data`: If given, parameters can also accept a string `s` interpreted as `data[s]`.

Also the colormap handling is different in matplotlib. Change `colormap` to `cmap` and call the `colorbar` manually:

```
ax.scatter(data=homicide_scatter_df, # define data source
           x='Homicide',             # column names
           y='Area Name',
           c='Population/mil',
           cmap='viridis',           # colormap -> cmap
           s=225, sharex=False)
plt.colorbar(label='Population/mil') # manually add colorbar
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually noticed that too. Both of these solutions work, and the last one is a neater way to arrange the data. The issue I have now is that "colormap is not in the object" error and even if removed from the second solution I do not get a color bar on the right of the chart with a color range and label "Population/mil" like I did in my first code example. Any ideas?

Comment: In matplotlib, the colormap param is `cmap`. For the colorbar, pandas calls it automatically, but to recreate it in matplotlib, it needs to be called manually.

Comment: There was more code involved, as needed to define a mappable. The new issue is the colours are going the wrong way now. The colours for the dots are correct and the bar with the numbers is correct, but for some reason; the colours on the bar are showing the wrong way. Should be yellow for highest pop.

Comment: Are the `Normalize` parameters backwards? I think `max` and `min` should be flipped: `norm = colors.Normalize(homicide_scatter_df['Population/mil'].min(), homicide_scatter_df['Population/mil'].max())`

Comment: First thing I tried and it made no difference to the bar colour order.

Comment: One option is adding `_r` to reverse it: `cmap='YlGnBu_r'`

Comment: If that still doesn't work, I suggest posting it as another question with sample data+code. Hard to debug that one with a runnable example that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I did that and noticed the colours were off. I looked and spotted that I had put in two different cmap colour ranges. Thanks for your help, you are a life saver. Clearly it is too late and I'm going to bed lol